# Running PowerShell from IIS Server does not work (OK on EasyPHP install, though!)

Tags: php, windows, powershell, batch-file, iis

I have searched for answers to this question, but the answers I've found do not seem to apply to my case. Or at least I was not able to understand them?
I'm working on an internal Web, so security is not the main issue.

I'm trying to launch scripts from the server.
I know that Web Servers are not really intended to do that, but again, security is not the issue, and scripts are intended to run on server side.

So far I'm able to launch batch scripts and even call some kind of ksh commands: OK.

For instance, if the PHP contains:
exec ('Test_ExecCmd.bat', $out);

and Test_ExecCmd.bat content is:
echo "Hello World" ;
whoami

Then $out array will contain "Hello World" and MyServerHost\MyAnonimousUser

Please note that "whoami" is a "ksh like" command, and it works fine here.

BUT when I try to put in a batch script the line:
powershell ls c:\
for instance, to list the content of c:\ the PHP script freezes and ends up with an error: "500 - Internal Server Error"

I have tried the same PHP + BAT sample on a locally installed EasyPHP, and it runs OK!!!!

So there it seems there is a specific tuning to be done on IIS, perhaps on its settings, authentication method or whatever.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue, please?
All suggestions are welcomed, thanks in advance!

Best regards,
  Jorge

Comment: First thing you should do is get the full error message. IIS hides it by default unless you're browsing the site from the server itself. So try to get a more complete error message and it may give some clue as to what is going on. Also check the application event log in Windows. You may find more information there, especially if the crash is happening in the runtime (an unhandled exception for instance).

Comment: Hello Briantist
I have no other error raised, only the "500 - Internal Server Error".
And it is strange, because the logs show the requests that went fine, but not these failing ones (c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2\u_ex161116).
Many thanks for your suggestion,
Best regards, Jorge

Comment: Check the Windows Event Logs, not the IIS web site logs. Run `eventvwr.msc` and look in the Application log.

Comment: :-O
I've run eventvwr.msc.
First I've cleaned all logs to easily find new events.
Then I've run my script.
New PowerShell events were raised, but nothing that helped me understand what could be wrong...
I've got events 400 and 403 (Engine Lifecycle) and 600 (Provider Lifecycle).
Only Information events, no error raised.
I'm going to continue my investigations.
Many thanks for your patience, attention and help.
Best regards, Jorge